# Angular Service - subscribe to component OnDestroy

Tags: angular

I have a service (`MyService`) that is injected in my `MyComponent`.  I want `MyComponent` to call a function on `MyService`, and pass some sort of a reference to this particular instance of `MyComponent` so that the service knows when the instance has been `destroyed`.

What is the proper object to pass to `MyService` from `MyComponent` so that `MyService` can know when the component is destroyed?  I am assuming there is a some sort of an observable `MyService` can subscribe to in order to get this information.

**EDIT:  Some more context**

`MyService`is in charge of creating `@angular/cdk Portal` and has two functions:

`attachComponent<T>(component: ComponentType<T>, data?: ComponentData<any>)`

and

`attachTemplate<T>(templateRef: TemplateRef<T>, viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef)`.

This service emits an observable that `MyHeaderComponent` subscribes to, in order to reflect some content that `MyComponent` has asked for it to render.  However, for clean-up reasons and so that every single other component doesn't have to import this service and clear the clontents of the header, I want to know when the caller of that function has been destroyed, and do it in the service so I only have to code it there.  Basically, the idea is, when the caller to either `attachTemplate` or `attachComponent` is destroyed, then the contents should be automatically cleared.  I'm trying to centralize this logic in `MyService` so that not every single component that injects `MyService` and uses this functionality has to implement some sort of a `clearContent()` function in ngOnDestroy.

Comment: you can call the method respective function in onDestroy hook

Comment: @Eftakhar I want to make this generic so that my `MyService` has this knowledge, and not have to call modify OnDestroy for every component that uses `MyService`

Comment: Just don't do that. Components depend on services, not vice-versa. This is an XY problem: you already chose a solution for an actual problem we don't know anything about, and are asking how to implement that solution. You should rather tell us what actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @JBNizet I added more context to the question

Answer (score 1):

Try to use subjects. You can create a subject in MyComponent and let MyService subscribe to that subject. You can call subject.complete() inside of your ngOnDestoy lifecycle hook of MyComponent. Then MyService will get to know the state of MyComponent. For reference about subjects:
https://ncjamieson.com/understanding-subjects/

Comment: Here is another article on this pattern: https://brianflove.com/2016/12/11/anguar-2-unsubscribe-observables/